# Who is this Salesforce mascot?

Tags: trailhead

I know all the others Salesforce characters (Astro, Codey, Cloudy, Appy, Chatty, SaaSy) but I can't figure out who this Raccoon is:

[image: mascot]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's **Earnie Badger**.

Earnie was introduced on [Salesforce's Official Blog](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2017/02/creative-force-behind-trailhead.html):

> **How do you see the Trailhead brand? Who are the main characters?**
>
> [...] Earnie Badger was made for our community of passionate badge-earners. [...]

Comment: Will this ever end? :(

Comment: Earnie is a female badger.

Comment: @matt I wonder if these are on topic. Maybe we should open up that conversation on Meta?

Comment: @AdrianLarson I don't even think they're on topic for an enterprise software company :)

Answer (score 6):

That must be Earnie, the new female badger. Heard about her the other day from someone in marketing., but she represents getting badges on Trailhead.

Comment: Earnie is a female badger.

Answer (score 3):

SHE is Earnie, a badger.

She was made for the community of badge-earners.

Answer (score 2):

This guy isn't an official character. However, Astro is technically a raccoon.
Updated from #TDX18 - this is Earnie Badger "Earnie hopes to become the first badger to earn Ranger status on Trailhead."

Comment: I thought Astro was a human that wears various costumes.

Comment: Not true. This FEMALE badger is an official character.

Comment: Sorry to downvote, but Astro is most definitely not a Raccoon. ;-)